# How to call javascript function from native c code in ios?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

We are developing an iPhone app using phonegap, we are facing a small problem.
We want to call a javascript function from native c code from appdelegate.m file.

Following is our javascript function in test.js file

```
function checkLink()
{  
    alert("Done..."); 
 }
```

I want to call the above function in appdelegate.m file in the below mentioned method

```
- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application
   {
      [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setApplicationIconBadgeNumber:0];   
    }
```

Any help will be appreciable.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `JavaScriptCore` framework that is bundled with `iOS 7`.

First you must create a global JS context, and load your js functions to it:

```
JSContext *context = [[JSContext alloc] init];  
[context evaluateScript:@"<testjsfiledata>"];
```

Then, you can call your functions as:

```
context[@"checkLink"] = ^() {
    // objective-c stuff
};
```